# Convert lwd unit to user coordinates (R base graphic)?

Tags: r, graphics

How can I use the `lwd` to represent some quantity?

For instance:

```
plot(NULL, type="n", xlim=c(4,7), ylim=c(1,6), xlab="", ylab="")
points(c(5.25,5.25), c(4,5), type="l", lwd=87)
points(c(5.5,6.5), c(3.5,3.5), type="l", lwd=92)
rect(5,3,5.5,4, col="white")
```

I want the lines drawn with the `points` functions exactly as wide/tall as the rectangle. The values 87 and 92 above I found manually. Is there a way to calculate those quantities?

EDIT:
The background for the question is: I want to draw [bezier curves](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/B%C3%A9zier_curves/Cubic#R), and I want the thickness of the curve represent my data. My first idea was to use `lwd` for that. Can I do better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lwd` is the wrong tool for what you're trying to do. The actual line width will change relative to user coordinates depending on how your plot window is resized (or the dimensions when you save it). You obviously know about the `rect` command, why not just use that? You might also look into the `shape` package.

--Edit--

For more complex shapes, my experience doesn't extend beyond `polygon`. With that, you could get the coordinates `bc` for a Bezier curve, and then draw a polygon around `x = c(bc$x + dx, rev(bc$x - dx), y = c(bc$y + dy, rev(bc$y - dy)`, but I'm not sure how well that would look for a complex curve.

As an aside, you can replace `points(..., type = "l")` with `lines(...)` if you'd like. (I think it makes my code more readable.)

Comment: I'd upvote twice for this answer if I could. +1 for `rect` advice and +1 for mention of 'shape' package. If the aspect ratio needs to be set there is an asp parameter to the `plot.window` function.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I edited my question to make it clearer. The `shape` vignette directed me to the `diagram` package I did not know about.

Comment: Thanks again, I now think `polygon` is the way to go. Something is wrong when curve is steep, but I hope I will figure it out.

Comment: @KarstenW. yeah, ideally to make the line of a constant thickness you'd choose points a constant distance away from the center in a direction orthogonal line.